# Centroid of quadrilateral on coordinate plane

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, centroid

I'm having trouble understanding the motivation between finding the centroid of a quadrilateral.

**Q: Find the centroid of a quadrilateral with vertices at (-8,12), (7,15) (13,-9), and (-2,-3).**

I've solved the problem, using the procedure described @[How can I construct the centroid of a quadrilateral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2484814/how-can-i-construct-the-centroid-of-a-quadrilateral?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) (by finding the intersection of the 4 centroids of the triangles formed by the 2 diagonals of a quadrilateral). However, I've been struggling to understand why this method gives the centroid of a quadrilateral (perhaps due to a theorem?).

** To clarify, I found the centroid which divides the quadrilateral into 4 equal areas

Comment: How do you intersect four points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key property, which can be derived by the definition, is that the centroid of a system of $2$ objects lies on the line which connects the centroid of each single object.

Then dividing the quadrilateral by a diagonal we find a first segment that contains the centroid of the quadrilateral and dividing by other diagonal we find a second segment that contains the centroid of the quadrilateral. Therefore the centroid coincides with the intersection of the two segments.

Comment: Is there a reason why the centroid of a system can't lie outside said segment?

Comment: Note that that $$\vec x_c=\frac{A_1}{A_1+A_2}\vec x_1+\frac{A_2}{A_1+A_2}\vec x_2=\frac{1}{1+A_2/A_1}\vec x_1+\frac{A_2/A_1}{1+A_2/A_1}\vec x_2=\frac{1}{1+a}\vec x_1+\frac{a}{1+a}\vec x_2=\frac{1}{1+a}\vec x_1+\frac{a}{1+a}\vec x_2=\frac{1+a-a}{1+a}\vec x_1+\frac{a}{1+a}\vec x_2=\vec x_1+\frac{a}{1+a}(\vec x_2-\vec x_1)$$ and for $a\in (0,\infty)$ it describe a line segment from the two centroids.